# Can you recommend a speech synthesiser for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, speechsynthesizer

I've used the built in speech synthesiser with C#/.NET but the options are limited and I'd like something more flexible. Any recommendations?

Comment: Which alternative speech synthesisers did you find so far?

Comment: What limitations are you running into ?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what kind of flexibility you need?

Answer (score 0):

The only direction I could point you in is the Microsoft Speech SDK (sapi), but i'm not sure if this is the one you are referring to that is inflexible.

[Microsoft Speech Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720151(v=VS.85).aspx)